# variadic arguments which are all a specialization of a template type

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, sfinae

We can validate at compile time that an input to a function is a specialization of a template. I.E the following code validates that the input for `f` is some specialization of struct Holder.

```
template<typename T>
struct Holder<T> {...};

template<typename T>
void f(Holder<T> h) {...};
```

I want to validate that a set of variadic arguments are a specialization of a template.
More precisely I want to differentiate between two consecutive sets of variadic arguments - a set which is a specialization of a template, and a set which isn't.
Following is an example of how it might have looked like if the syntax allowed it to -

```
template<...Args1, ...Args2>
void f(Holder<Args1>.... args_which_are_specializations_of_Holder, Args2... args_which_are_not) {
  use_holders(args_which_are_specializations_of_Holder...);
  use_rest(args_which_are_not...);
  return;
}
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks,

Comment: This is not possible, but a completely unrelated reason: two variadic parameter packs are not going to deduce the way you think they will deduce.

Comment: what do you mean? and can i change the signature somehow to that they will ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the `args` in a `tuple` and calculate the index of the last `Holder` argument, then extract the `Holder` and normal arguments by index and forward them to the corresponding function.

```
#include <tuple>

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_holder = false;
template<class T>
constexpr bool is_holder<Holder<T>> = true;

template<class... Args>
void f(Args... args) {
  constexpr auto holder_index = (is_holder<Args> + ... + 0);
  auto args_tuple = std::tuple(args...);

  [&args_tuple]<auto... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    use_holders(std::get<Is>(args_tuple)...);
  }(std::make_index_sequence<holder_index>{});

  [&args_tuple]<auto... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    use_rest(std::get<Is + holder_index>(args_tuple)...);
  }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - holder_index>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mv76rbGfs)

Comment: somehow use_rest gets all the inputs, including the holder. Not sure what the issue is, but I made it work for what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's harder to mix variadic arguments like that. You can use `std::tuple`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdio>

template<class T>
struct Holder {
    T value;
};

template <class ...T1, class ...T2>
void f(const std::tuple<Holder<T1>...>& holders, const std::tuple<T2...>& non_holders) {
  std::printf("Holder count: %zu\n"
              "Non-holder count: %zu\n", sizeof...(T1), sizeof...(T1));
}

int main() {
  Holder<int> a{};
  Holder<double> b{};
  int c{};
  double d{};  

  f(std::tuple{a, b}, std::tuple{c, d});
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. But I wonder if it's possible to remove the tuple creation when calling f? I think the second tuple isn't needed at all. And maybe the first one can be removed by some kind implicit cast to a tuple? trying to play with it, but unable so far to remove the first tuple.

Comment: @NimrodFiat if you remove the second tuple, it becomes more fragile.